# How to return to previous URL after login? (ajax)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, authorize-attribute, form-authentication

So I have a MVC5 web application (it came with ASP.Identity framework) and I have this custom `Authorize` attribute.

```
public class FrontEndAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        dynamic user = (ClaimsPrincipal)httpContext.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            dynamic urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
            context.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;

            context.Result = new JsonResult {
                Data = new {
                    Error = "NotAuthorized",
                    LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("LogIn", "Account")
                },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        } else {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have some problem with ajax method. For example if I have Articles page `warheat1990.com/articles/batman-arkham-knight-review` with a button to submit comment.

```
[HttpPost]
[FrontEndAuthorize]
public ActionResult SubmitComment(string comment)
{
    //code here
    return Content("success");
}
```

And I have a script to call the method when user click the Submit Comment button.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Articles/SubmitComment/'
    type: 'POST'
    //rest of code here
})
```

When user click the Submit Comment button without LogIn first, the user will be redirected to LogIn page, however on LogIn success, user is taken back to Home page aka `warheat1990.com` instead of `warheat1990.com/articles/batman-arkham-knight-review`.

This is cause by `SubmitComment` method is called from ajax. So my question is what should I do to be able to redirect user to previous page on ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is that your HandleUnauthorizedRequest method needs to provide a "return to" parameter to the page/controller handling the login.  Instead of sending your user to just the login page:

```
LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("LogIn", "Account")
```

You would provide an additional `returnUrl` query param:

```
// for your ajax
LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("LogIn", "Account", new { returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl })

// for your non-ajax:
context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                    {                     
                            { "controller", "Account" },
                            { "action", "Login" },
                            { "returnUrl", context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
                    });
```

The user would land on a page like:

```
warheat1990.com/login?returnUrl=warheat1990.com%2Farticles%2Fbatman-arkham-knight-review
```

If login succeeds, then you would parse the request for the query param `returnUrl` value (if it exists), and redirect the user to that location.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the caller url like below

```C#
if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
                context.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;

                /* Get return url */
                var returnUrl = context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
                context.Result = new JsonResult
                    {
                        Data = new
                            {
                                Error = "NotAuthorized",
                                LogOnUrl = urlHelper.Action("LogIn", "Account", new {returnUrl})
                            },
                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    };
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
            }
```

and in account controller and index action redirect to that url

```C#
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
           /* Together with some other code */
           return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get previous request by Request.UrlReferrer or Request.ServerVariables["http_referer"].

Then once you are done with login process you can redirect to this url